# Java: unconditional jump to outer scope at any place

Tags: java

Lets say I have a program that performs foo. baz is a new function that needs testing.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  foo ();   // existing

  baz ();  // new
}
```

For testing baz I will put it in front of foo. So no need to wait for foo.

And I also want to end (jump to outer scope) after baz. It is about testing baz and I want to quit after that. But I do not want to put foo in comments (maybe it is much more complex code than 1 line).

The best I have in mind is this.

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
   baz (); 
   if (1==1) return;  // unconditional jump to outer scope

   foo ();
}
```

I do not like this

> if(1==1)

but I do not know any alternative.

A simple return is not allowed (compiler-error, unreachable code).

A System.exit would only work if we talk about main but not if my code is in some greater context. I want to return to the outer scope.

Any better ideas for that?

Comment: That's a very odd way of testing. But I don't see why it would be relevant if you immediately remove it after the quick test again.

Comment: FYI, you can replaced `1==1` with `true`. Or you can avoid the warning by replacing an expression that's true by definition with one that's only logically true (e.g. `System.currentTimeMillis() > 0`). But I have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish. There's a reason why the compiler doesn't allow code after an unconditional return.

Comment: You could just use `if (true) return;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One alternative is to use the industry standard approach for test-driven-development (TDD).

Write a unit test using a standard test runner such as [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit5/) or [TestNG](https://testng.org/).  If you take this approach you will not have to modify your production code simply to test it.

From your test class, call `baz()` directly. As an added benefit, you now also have a test that will validate the behavior of this method now and in the future.

I suggest you read up on the topic of TDD.  There are many good resources available.  It is not a silver bullet, but there are many benefits to using this approach.